# Byobu terminal can't use tmux

Tags: bash, tmux, byobu

I can't enable tmux feature on byobu terminal or on any terminal.

I run `echo $TERM` and i get

> screen-256color

When i run `tmux` i get this:

> sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force

```
tmux ls
```

> 1: 1 windows (created Sun May 26 20:01:01 2019) [80x23] (attached)

For xfce terminal with out tmux

> xterm-256color

When i execute

```
echo $TERM
```

I get this:

> screen

And i can use the tmux feature CTL-b : only when i command the tmux

I run the command:

```
byobu-select-backend
```

And i select the tmux, but nothing

Config for byobu:

```
set -g mode-mouse on
set-option -g history-limit 2000000
set -g default-shell /usr/bin/zsh
set -g default-command /usr/bin/zsh
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish. In your first example, you are already in a TMUX session. That is what `sessions should be nested with care` is referring to. You CAN start a new tmux process under an existing one, but its not to be trifled with until you thoroughly understand TMUX and know what difficulties can arise.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know that Byobu don't use the tmux setting and that it have it own.